# Need to get latest record for two values, then use that to get the oldest -MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

Update: The version of server I'm working with is MySQL 5.7

I've got basic knowledge of SQL but once it gets into multiple inner joins and queries, I completely lose track of what I need to do.

So, I need to do two things.

- First I need to get the latest record for profile and type as a profile can have a or b type
- With that information, I then need to get the earliest record when that profile and type are in the table

Since I know I've explained this badly, here I have setup information from two tables

```
SELECT a.profile_id,a.id, a.created_at, b.type
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.p_id = b.id
```

| a.profile | a.id | a.created_at | b.type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1325586 | 340807 | 2021-08-05 21:30:55 | A |
| 1325586 | 340803 | 2021-08-05 21:28:11 | A |
| 1325586 | 340805 | 2021-08-05 21:28:11 | A |
| 1325487 | 340707 | 2021-06-26 13:42:19 | B |
| 1325487 | 340453 | 2021-03-25 10:49:40 | A |
| 1325487 | 340451 | 2021-03-25 10:49:39 | A |

With the information above I want to get the following two records

| a.profile | a.id | a.created_at | b.type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1325586 | 340803 | 2021-08-05 21:28:11 | A |
| 1325487 | 340707 | 2021-06-26 13:42:19 | B |

So it needs to first find out what the latest type is with a profile and then get the first record where that type was used. Does that make sense?

I've tried a few methods but at a certain point I get stumped. I've only really got the following which will get my the records based on the max(id)

```
SELECT a.profile,a.id, a.created_at, b.type
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.p_id = b.id 
WHERE (a.id, a.profile) in 
(Select max(aa.id), aa.profile from tableA aa 
GROUP BY aa.profile)
```

Comment: This would be waaaay easier and more efficient with windowing functions, which are avialable on MySql 8.0 and later

Comment: Agreed but I'm only working with this, not my decision on when to upgrade etc :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need twice row_number fist  for the max and then for the Mim as well, so you get only one row per profile

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tableA (
>   `profile_id` INTEGER,
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `created_at` datetime,
>   tableA int
>   
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tableA
>   (`profile_id`, `id`, `created_at`)
> VALUES
>   ('1325586', '340807', '2021-08-05 21:30:55'),
>   ('1325586', '340803', '2021-08-05 21:28:11'),
>   ('1325586', '340805', '2021-08-05 21:28:11'),
>   ('1325487', '340707', '2021-06-26 13:42:19'),
>   ('1325487', '340453', '2021-03-25 10:49:40'),
>   ('1325487', '340451', '2021-03-25 10:49:39');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tableB (p_id int,`type` VARCHAR(1))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tableB VALUES(340807,'A'),(340803,'A'),(340805,'A'),(340707,'B'),(340453,'A'),(340451,'A')
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS(SELECT a.profile_id,a.id, a.created_at, b.type
> FROM tableA a
> JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.p_id 
> )
> SELECT
> `profile_id`, `id`, `created_at`, `type`
> FROM
> (SELECT 
> t1.* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION  BY `profile_id` ORDER BY created_at ASC) rn
> FROM CTE t1
>  INNER JOIN (SELECT `profile_id`, `type`
> FROM (
> SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION  BY `profile_id` ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn FROM CTE) ta
> WHERE rn = 1) t2 ON t1.`profile_id` =  t2.`profile_id` AND  t1.`type` = t2.`type`) tb 
> WHERE rn = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> profile_id |     id | created_at          | type
> ---------: | -----: | :------------------ | :---
>    1325487 | 340707 | 2021-06-26 13:42:19 | B   
>    1325586 | 340803 | 2021-08-05 21:28:11 | A
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c7bfaee26d0be65771a6351a5af0673)*

For Mysql 5.7 this gets uglier

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tableA (
>   `profile_id` INTEGER,
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `created_at` datetime,
>   tableA int
>   
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tableA
>   (`profile_id`, `id`, `created_at`)
> VALUES
>   ('1325586', '340807', '2021-08-05 21:30:55'),
>   ('1325586', '340803', '2021-08-05 21:28:11'),
>   ('1325586', '340805', '2021-08-05 21:28:11'),
>   ('1325487', '340707', '2021-06-26 13:42:19'),
>   ('1325487', '340453', '2021-03-25 10:49:40'),
>   ('1325487', '340451', '2021-03-25 10:49:39');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tableB (p_id int,`type` VARCHAR(1))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tableB VALUES(340807,'A'),(340803,'A'),(340805,'A'),(340707,'B'),(340453,'A'),(340451,'A')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `profile_id`, `id`, `created_at`, `type`
> FROM
> (SELECT IF(a.profile_id = @profile, @rn := @rn +1, @rn:= 1) rn,a.id, a.created_at, b.type,
> @profile := a.profile_id as profile_id
> FROM tableA a
> JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.p_id
> JOIN
> (SELECT profile_id,type
> FROM
> (SELECT IF(a.profile_id = @profile, @rn := @rn +1, @rn:= 1) rn,a.id, a.created_at, b.type,
> @profile := a.profile_id as profile_id
> FROM tableA a
> JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.p_id , (SELECT @profile := 0, @rn := 0 ) t1
> ORDEr BY a.profile_id,a.created_at DESC) ta
> WHERE rn = 1) tb ON a.profile_id = tb.profile_id AND b.type = tb.type,(SELECT @profile := 0, @rn := 0 ) t1
> ORDER BY a.profile_id,a.created_at ASC) tc
> WHERE rn = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> profile_id |     id | created_at          | type
> ---------: | -----: | :------------------ | :---
>    1325586 | 340807 | 2021-08-05 21:30:55 | A   
>    1325487 | 340707 | 2021-06-26 13:42:19 | B
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c4956d7e987c05fbf558c1e1996def9b)*

Comment: Unfortunately I see the MySQL Server I'm working with is on v5.7

Comment: I added a 5.7 Version

Comment: Need to sort out some extra conditions myself but this looks to be on the right track. Thanks

Comment: Have it working as I want now, this is exactly what I needed